# How do I limit the amount of sediment in bottles?

Tags: brewing, bottle-conditioning

I recently made my second batch of beer.  It's a pumpkin ale.  I am finding that the bottles contain a large amount of sediment, almost like slush at the bottom the bottle.  The beer is delicious, but I'm wondering how I can prevent this in the future.  My first batch of beer was the White House Honey Ale and those were pretty much sediment free.

What influences the amount of sediment?  Should I be "filtering" at some point in the process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about homebrew and belongs on [homebrew.se]

Comment: Oh - sorry about that.  Was not aware of Homebrewing.