# Using Caster Sugar as Primer in Barrell

Tags: ale

I'll admin i got a bit excited. My first best of home brew fermented for 6 days, then transferred to barrel for the net 3 weeks - i used woodforde's real ale mix.

BUT at the last seconds i forgot primer so i improvised wit 80g of caster sugar for 23 litres of beer.

Does anyone have experience of using caster sugar as a primer in a barrell? And more importantly - have i just borked my first barrell?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about home brewing and not really appropriate for this site.

Comment: and this one wasn't? http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/how-do-i-limit-the-amount-of-sediment-in-bottles

Comment: We've discussed this a bit on Meta since the beta started and the consensus has been that home-brew questions are allowed if also seem like they might be generally interesting to beer folks...The more technical and home-brew process specific a question is, the more likely it is to be seen off as off-topic.  For now I'm not going to vote to close, and will contribute an answer but for the future making and preparing the beer should be in homebrew.SE but handling and serving the beer will go over just fine here.  (homebrew.SE also gets way more traffic that we do)

Comment: ah i see. Sorry guys i didn't realise there was a homebrewing forum. I'll put this question on there.

Comment: I'm with @Sloloem, but closing because OP posted the question here: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/15193/using-caster-sugar-as-a-barrel-primer-bad-idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the math out, assuming my liters to US Gallons conversion by Google is accurate, that would come out to around 1.6-1.7 volumes of CO2 in the beer which is on the lower end of carbonation but probably appropriate for many European ale styles.

Think of something like a Bitter or ESB, that's probably where you'll end up.

Caster sugar is just very fine white sugar, so it's probably some form of sucrose...pretty much all of which are interchangeable.  If this is under carbonated for the style you're going for, check out an online carbonation or priming sugar calculator next time and just pitch sugar according to that.

I always liked [Northern Brewer's](http://www.northernbrewer.com/priming-sugar-calculator/).  It takes beer in gallons since it's a US site but I like that they have a style drop down and list how much of many different types of sugar to use.